# How to load geojson features outside view with Mapbox GL?

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to load all features from an imported geoJSON. I want to do so because I need some propeties in order to create a list of all elements.

But when trying to access them it looks like I can only query the features inside the current view.

Is there a way to acces them even if they are not in the current view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) the GeoJSON first and then pass the GeoJSON object instead of URL as the [`geojson` source's data](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource).